# How to copy paste from OneNote to Quality Center?

Tags: quality-center

Steps:

- Select a block of text in OneNote.
- Copy to clipboard
- Paste in Quality Center (defect description field or actual box of manual runner)

Expected result: text is pasted in Quality Center.
Actual result: nothing happens.

Workaround: copy paste to and from notepad.

Versions used: Microsoft OneNote 2010, Quality Center 10.00

Comment: I have this exact same problem, could any one please tell how to copy clipboard content to defect fields like description using OTA API and VBA code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use QC, but I've run across other apps that won't accept formatted text (or more often, there's something in the formatting they don't like, so they reject the entire paste command).

I run a utility called [PureText](http://stevemiller.net/puretext/) that enables me to paste the plain-text version of any clipboard text with a single keystroke (I use Win-v). It saves me from the notepad paste conversion routine.

Comment: Thanks, this is an acceptable workaround while waiting for a real solution.

Comment: I was very frustrated with a very similar problem only a few days ago. In particular, when pasting data from Excel into Outlook, or from the web into Outlook, I don't want to have to whip out the format painter, or wait for it to render the formatted text just for me to remove all its formatting anyway. It works 'as expected' right out of the box. Very nice.